# How to add a Servlet filter in Vert.x REST API?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, vert.x, aws-xray

I have a REST API which was created purely using Vert.x, I would like to instrument it for AWS X-RAY and in order to do that I need to add a servlet filter. I'm creating a webserver like this:

```
vertx.createHttpServer()
      .requestHandler(r -> r.response().end("Welcome to Vert.x Intro");
      })
      .listen(config().getInteger("http.port", 9090), 
        result -> {
          if (result.succeeded()) {
              future.complete();
          } else {
              future.fail(result.cause());
          }
      });
```

In the documentation for AWS X-RAY they've only mentioned Tomcat (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-filters.html). Would adding filters using `web.xml` work for this as well or do I need to do something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think AWS X-Ray will not work with vert.x - I found no mention of them being used together.

I would probably try to apply spring example from their site but according to [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61605979/aws-x-ray-instrumentation-with-vertx-microservices-build-in-java) it might be in vain. It seems vert.x architecture is not compatible with X-Ray.